# Error en sintaxys 'semicolon' y expected input end

Tags: mysql, trigger

Quisiera ayuda para solucionar este trigger que me arroja errores en la linea de VALUES dice

> "syntax error: missing 'semicolon`'

.
Y en la ultima linea en el END aparece

> "syntax error: extraneus input found - expected end of input...

este es mi script:

```
create trigger trigger_upd_profesor after update on profesor
for each row 
begin
insert into trigger_profesor(id_trigger,tipo_trigger,doc_prof,nom_prof,ape_prof,cat_prof,sal_prof)
values (null, 'update', new.doc_prof, new.nom_prof, new.ape_prof, new.cat_prof, new.sal_prof);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

En este caso debes hacer uso de [`DELIMITER ;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346637/what-does-delimiter-do-in-a-trigger) (con espacio).

```
DELIMITER $$

create trigger trigger_upd_profesor after update on profesor
for each row 
begin
insert into trigger_profesor(id_trigger,tipo_trigger,doc_prof,nom_prof,ape_prof,cat_prof,sal_prof)
values (null, 'update', new.doc_prof, new.nom_prof, new.ape_prof, new.cat_prof, new.sal_prof);
end; $$

DELIMITER ;
```